# Trying to repeat a non-background image

Tags: html, css, image, repeat

Im trying to repeat-y an image, but everything I have tried does not work.

HTML Body Code:

```
<body>
    <h1>Native Flowers</h1>
    <div id="header"></div>
    <div id="navBar">
        <ul>
        <li>Home</li>
        <li>Other</li>
        <li>Other</li>
        <li>Other</li>
        <li>Other</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <img class="pinkTex" src="res/pinkTex.jpg"/>
</body>
```

This is the code for the body of my HTML file currently.

CSS pinkTex:

```
.pinkTex {
left: 0px;
height: 100%;
width: 200px;
}
```

At the moment this is the code for the pinkTex class for the img.

So if I can please get some help on how to repeat this y-axis, that would be great. Thanks You.

Answer (score 1):

if you give image in body tag use this code and please make sure your image path is proper.

```
 body
    {
        background-image: url("res/pinkTex.jpg");
        background-repeat: repeat-y;
    }
```

you can use also

```
 .pinkTex
    {
        left: 0px;
        height: 100%;
        width: 200px;
        background-image: url("res/pinkTex.jpg");
        background-repeat: repeat-y;
    }
```

Comment: It works when the height isnt 100% and its like 1000px, but i dont want that